# how can I make a cascading drop down list for car make/model in php?

Tags: php, html

** ive done some html and php code below but for some reason im not able to make the model drop down list dependent to the make drop down list in php. so ive made an html form and then i tried to make the cascading drop down list in php but its not working **

** php code I've done **

```
 if (empty($_POST['car'])){
                $errors[] = 'Make is required.';
            }
     
            elseif($_POST['car']=="Toyota"){
                $car = trim($_POST['car']);
                $ToyotaModel = trim($_POST['ToyotaModel']);
                echo "<h1> the make is : </h1>" .$_POST['car'];
                echo "<h1> model is </h1>" .strip_tags($_POST['ToyotaModel']);
            }
            elseif($_POST['car']=="Nissan"){
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<h1> the make is : </h1>" .$_POST['car'];
                echo "<h1> model is </h1>" .strip_tags($_POST['NissanModel']);
            }

            elseif($_POST['car']=="Mercedez"){
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<h1> the make is : </h1>" .$_POST['car'];
                echo "<h1> model is </h1>" .strip_tags($_POST['MercedezModel']);
            }
            else{
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<h3> you didnt enter car make </h3>";
            }
```

** html code**

```
<form action="register_car.php" method="POST" class="form">
      <h2>Car Registration Form</h2>
      <div class="mb-3">
        

          <input type="radio" name="car" id="Toyota" value="Toyota"/>

          <label for="Toyota" class="form-label">Toyota</label>
          <select name="ToyotaModel" class="form-control" >
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="Camri">Camri</option>
            <option value="Corolla">Corolla</option>
            <option value="Estima">Estima</option>
          </select><br>

          <input type="radio" name="car" id="Nissan" value="Nissan"/>

          <label for="Nissan" class="form-label">Nissan</label>
          <select name="NissanModel" class="form-control" >
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="Micra">Micra</option>
            <option value="roller">roller</option>
            <option value="fushe">fushe</option>
          </select><br>

          <input type="radio" name="car" id="Mercedez" value="Mercedez"/>

          <label for="Mercedez" class="form-label">Mercedez</label>
          <select name="MercedezModel" class="form-control" >
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="5series">5series</option>
            <option value="x7">x7</option>
            <option value="x5">x5</option>
          </select><br>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: So, my is form displaying and when i select the make toyota, then automatically the models of toyota should appear in the following drop down list but thats not happening

Comment: There's no code here to make any drop-down lists, or items in them "appear". There are three radio buttons, three drop-down lists, and code to display what you selected after you submit the form.

Comment: so what is the approach to do that?

Comment: If you want it to happen immediately in the browser, you'll need to learn some JavaScript - PHP runs on the server, so can only look at what's selected after the form has been submitted back to the server. Have a look online for JavaScript tutorials; there will be probably be lots of examples of similar logic.